# How to use relative paths for images while maintaining a directory structure in angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angularJS for implementation. I have created a directory structure for my application so that html pages and js will be identified.  I have created a header.html which contains only header part of my application. I am including the header.html by using ng-inlcude in my dashboard page which is on root, in this header.html page I am using some image tags like src="theme/img/logo/my_logo.png".
When I am trying to use the header.html in some of other HTML page which is in directory structure I am not able to get the image on the src in header.html. So to get the image I need to use src="../theme/img/logo/my_logo.png".

Can anyone please give me the solution how I can to use relative or context  path for image so that the header.html can work for root pages as well for the pages which are in directory structure.

Thanking You.

Sachin Warke.

Answer (score 0):

Set a base url with

```
<base href="<path here>">
```

if you don't want to use absolute urls.

Comment: Thanks Anders Bornholm. I will try this.